# Why is response.urljoin() not getting all the URL in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

When I'm scraping a URL or replacing in URL with `%20` to handle spaces, scrapy is not getting the whole URL. It is only showing half as in the linked image.

Can anybody tell me why scrapy isn't getting the whole URL with `response.urljoin()`?.

Error message:

> 2020-01-07 23:09:19 [scrapy.pipelines.files] WARNING: File (code: 302): Error downloading file from http://www.oriental-patron.com.hk/opsl/dl_count.php?id=1986&type=company&pdf_path=/u
>   pload/File/Q%20Tech%20(1478%20HK)%20-%20Top-up%20placement%20for%20CCM%20capacity%20expansion%20-%20BUY.pdf> referred in 
>   2020-01-07 23:09:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.oriental-patron.com.hk/opsl/eng/company.php?display=all>
>   {'file_urls': ['**http://www.oriental-patron.com.hk/opsl/dl_count.php?id=1977&type=company&pdf_path=/upload/File/Sunny%20Optical%20**(2382%20HK)%20-%20October%20shipments%20in%20line%20with%20e
>   xpectations%20-%20BUY.pdf'],
>    'files': []}

[Link to picture]

Comment: Could you please share analysis done for the issue mentioned in more descriptive manner, it would help others provide answers/solution to your issue.

Comment: What makes you say that Scrapy does not get the URL? The screenshot shows the whole URL (only part in blue, but it is not Scrapy who paints URLs there, it is your editor or terminal)

Answer (score 0):

You have parentheses in the URL. It looks like Scrapy chokes on them. They are "semi-reserved" in URL's, but ought to be OK where you have them. To be on the safe side you should encode them.
In general you shouldn't do url-encoding by hand, but rely on built-in measures. As I understand it, you should do this in Python:

```py
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.quote(url)
```

but I don't know Python.

Comment: Thanks for your reply you can see above I mentioned the error properly